# py3270 - error: The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: python, automation, mainframe

I am trying to connect mainframe server using below snippet;

Objective: Automating mainframe flow using python, using py3270 and wc3270 emulator

```
import time, sys
from py3270 import Emulator

delayt = 1    # In sec, slowing down to be able to see the screen update
mylogin = '[xxxxxx]'
mypass = '[xxxxxxx]'
myhost = '[xxxxxxxxx]:5037'
screenrows = []

# use x3270 so you can see what is going on
my3270 = Emulator(visible=True)
    

# TSO login
my3270.connect(myhost)
my3270.wait_for_field()
#my3270.send_clear()
```

I am getting following error:
SSL: InitializeSecurityContext: error 0x80090322 (The target principal name is incorrect.)

I have gone through some blogs and found that cert validation can be the issue and by disabling that it can be fixed: https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=5747

Can someone suggest if any function/attribute available which can disable cert validation while connection; similar to "wc3270.verifyHostCert: false"

Or any other ideas....

Thanks!

Comment: What about asking your mainframe guys to install a valid certificate?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace to help identify where the problem is occurring?  Knowing the component will help us help you.